# Can linter-flake8 ignore files by using a project-wide .flake8rc?

Tags: atom-editor, flake8

I'm using Atom and [linter-flake8](https://atom.io/packages/linter-flake8) for my project. I have a set of huge generated Python files and I want them ignored by linter-flake8. These files are placed in a folder called `generated/`, inside the project root folder. At the same level with the `generated/` folder, I placed a .flake8rc with the following content:

```
[flake8]
exclude=generated/
```

and configured linter-flake8 to use this file (via Preferences in Atom). However, it still parses those files. What am I doing wrong?

PS: If I run `flake8 --exclude=generated/ .` in bash, in the project root folder, it works fine and ignores my files.

Comment: Have you instead attempted to use the files that flake8 finds on its own? `setup.cfg`, `tox.ini`, `.flake8` should all work

Comment: I did, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, I'm using a global .flake8rc for now.